# How to load tensorflow metagraph via C++

Tags: tensorflow

I want to load a metagraph via C++ code, and later the checkpoint weights. To load the metagraph, I first generate a pb file from it

`with tf.Session() as sess:
    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(root_dir + meta_graph)
    tf.train.write_graph(sess.graph_def, root_dir, export_pb, as_text=False)`

Then I use selective registration to generate the ops and kernels needed

`bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/print_selective_registration_header --graphs=xinmei/rnn_dict/model_test.pb > tensorflow/core/framework/ops_to_register.h`

Next, I compile my runnable using this registration. However, when I run the executable on my Android device, it says

```
Error creating graph: Invalid argument: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'Const' with these attrs.  Registered devices: [CPU], Registered kernels:
  <no registered kernels>

     [[Node: save/RestoreV2_8/shape_and_slices = Const[_output_shapes=[[1]], dtype=DT_STRING, value=Tensor<type: string shape: [1] values: >]()]]
```

How can I load the metagraph? The motivation of this is that I want to continue training the model on my Android device.